# Update entities in Entity Framework automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have a simple database and I use `Entity Framework` to perfom queries.

**Customer.cs**

```
namespace DataAccess.Entities
{
    [Table("Customer")]
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
     }
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
public partial class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(e => e.CustomerName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Status>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Customer)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Status)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

But if my database change, how to update my entities and the `OnModelCreating` method ? Without do this manually ?

Thank's

Comment: what do you mean by "my database change"? The data in it or the architecture (columns, constrains, etc.)?

Comment: hello, the architecture

Comment: Isn't the trigger to change the DB architecture is the model? I mean, to change the architechture you need to change your model and you shouldn't do it from the DB itself

Comment: Are you using code first approach or database first? From the code posted it looks like code first approach?

Comment: Ok, so I must to use migrations to push my changes ?

Comment: @Vijay Yes Code First

Comment: @Azerty123 as you commented you should make the change and push it using migrations.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use "code first" approach every change to the DB should be done via models, so you shouldn't deal with the problem you've stated and you can assume the DB structure matches the model

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net MVC, you can use Migrations in Package Manager Console as shown below.

1. enable-migrations
2. add-migration InitialModel
3. Update-database

For default data/enums you should use seeding. For seeding in Package Manager Console

1. add-migration PopulateStatus

a partial class with the name **PopulateStatus** will open, in up() method, you should write the SQl commands to insert default data. In your case its Status table. Then update database command in package manager

2. Update-database

For better understanding you can look [here](http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.in/2016/12/code-first-migrations-in-mvc-5.html)

Comment: No It's a WCF project. But I have a sql server project. And I deploy Dacpac for update architecture of my database

Comment: Hi Azerty123, you can do the same way in WCF project also if entityframework is installed/reference to the project.

Comment: But I want to keep my other project and manage the database with dacpac. I don't want to use migrations in my WCF project and I don't want to use edmx for update my entities